# issue EFI USB Device (....) boot failed. in framework pc with specific OS (tuxedo OS 2)

Tags: boot, amd

I have created a bootable usb using balenaEtcher of the tuxedo OS 2 iso file to setup my new framework 13 pc (amd ryzen processor). the thing is, when I turn on the pc, I get the error:

EFI USB Device (kingstonDataTraveler 3.0) boot failed.

with the same workflow using kubuntu iso it works correctly, nevertheless I would really prefere to use tuxedo OS 2 if possible. tuxedo normally it is also based in ubuntu. anyone that has an idea how could I solve this issue to be able to use it?
some extra info: I have tried with different usbs (with the same usb kubuntu works) and also in usb A and c ports... I also turned off 'quick boot' in the bios
thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that secure boot was enabled. Once I disabled that it worked smoothly.